# Where to initialize a serialization field that is validated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

My model has a `serialize :settings` field. It is also validated by some custom validation. I now want to initialize that field when an object is created (`self.settings = Settings.new`). So I tried to it in an `after_initialization` callback. But that gives me `Can't convert Settings into String`. The same happens when using the `before_validation` callback.
But when assigning the Setting.new manually after the object was built there is no problem at all. Why can't I use those callbacks to set serialization fields? (Rails3)

Comment: Interesting - what happens if you try to initialize it with something like a Hash or an Array?

Comment: Cory is right to ask that. also,  what happens if you do this YAML::dump(Settings.new)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `:settings` field is in fact of type `:text` rather than `:string`. It might help you to check out : [something similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database/6702790#comment13132172_6702790)