# Using Rails serialize to save hash to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, activerecord

I'm try to save a hash mapping ids to a number of attempts in my rails app. My migration to the database to accommodate this new column:

```
class AddMultiWrongToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :multi_wrong, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :multi_wrong
  end
end
```

In my model I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
 serialize :multi_wrong, Hash
end
```

But when I use the rails console to test this by doing:

```
user = User.create()
user.multi_wrong = {"test"=>"123"}
user.save
```

The output is false. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Is there anything in user.errors after attempting to save the record?

Comment: In the future, you can use the bang method (save!) to raise an exception and display an error message.

Comment: Best answer now uses a JSON column https://stackoverflow.com/a/21397522/1536309

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The column type is wrong. You should use Text instead of String. Therefore, your migration should be:

```
 def self.up
   add_column :users, :multi_wrong, :text
 end
```

Then Rails will properly convert it into YAML for you (and perform proper serialization). Strings fields are limited in size and will only hold especially-small values.

Comment: @BenjaminTan what is the reason behind it,why does I can't store hash in 'string' data type.

Comment: Because in the database, String has a fixed length of 255 (I think). But if you were to serialize a hash of comparative size, this would easily exceed the length. Same case for Arrays. Text allows for much bigger lengths.

Answer (score 77):

**UPDATED:**

Exact implementation will depend on your database, but PostgreSQL now has `json` and `jsonb` columns which can natively store your hash/object data and allow you to [query against the JSON with ActiveRecord](https://www.tachyonstemplates.com/2018/rails-postgres-query-json/)!

change your migration and you're done.

```
class Migration0001
  def change
    add_column :users, :location_data, :json, default: {}
  end
end
```

**ORIGINAL:**

For more details: **[rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Saving+arrays-2C+hashes-2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns)** && **[apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize)**

Make sure your column is `:text` and not `:string`

**Migration:**

`$ rails g migration add_location_data_to_users location_data:text`

should create:

```
class Migration0001
  def change
    add_column :users, :location_data, :text
  end
end
```

**Your Class Would Look Like:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :location_data
end
```

**Available Actions:**

```
b = User.new
b.location_data = [1,2,{foot: 3, bart: "noodles"}]
b.save
```

**More Awesome?!**

utilize postgresql hstore

```
class AddHstore < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def up
    enable_extension :hstore
  end

  def down
    disable_extension :hstore
  end
end 

class Migration0001
  def change
    add_column :users, :location_data, :hstore
  end
end
```

**With hstore you can set attributes on the serialized field**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  # setup hstore
  store_accessor :location_data, :city, :state
end
```

Comment: Truly awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Rails 4 has a new feature called [Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html), so you can easily use it to solve your problem. You can define an accessor for it and it is recommended you declare the database column used for the serialized store as a text, so there's plenty of room. The original example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :homepage ], coder: JSON
end

u = User.new(color: 'black', homepage: '37signals.com')
u.color                          # Accessor stored attribute
u.settings[:country] = 'Denmark' # Any attribute, even if not specified with an accessor

# There is no difference between strings and symbols for accessing custom attributes
u.settings[:country]  # => 'Denmark'
u.settings['country'] # => 'Denmark'
```