# Save a Hash in Mysql using ruby and read as hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code is this

```
   leads_hash={"509351475764673"=>{"sc"=>0, "ct"=>#<OrderedHash {"2013-02-10"=>1}>, "ml"=>0}, "473882175995429"=>{"sc"=>0, "ct"=>0, "ml"=>0}}
    obj=User.new()
    obj.leads_hash=leads_hash

obj.save!
```

and in model i defined

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :leads_hash
end
```

but it save as a string how can i solve this please someone help me

~

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Rails serialize to save hash to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database)

Comment: It will save as as a string in the database, but Rails will deserialize on load. What is the issue you have?

Comment: but its not deserialize for me ,when i fired this query data=User.find_by_id(1) and data.leads_hash.class.to_s it gives String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that leads_hash is stored as a `text` and not a `string` in your migration. For reference, check out a similar question: [Using Rails serialize to save hash to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database/6702790#6702790)