# How to load the mail serve configuration during start time in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer

In our rails app, we would like to load the mail server configuration during the startup. Here is the what we have in config/environment/development.rb:

```
  #Action Mailer
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = eval(Authentify::AuthentifyUtility.find_config_const('development_smtp_setting'))
```

The  `Authentify::AuthentifyUtility.find_config_const('development_smtp_setting')` shall return:

```
 {  
   :address              => "mymail.com",  
    :port                 => 587,    
    :user_name            => "smtp_login_name",  
    :password             => "password",  
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => false
  }
```

However `rails server` throws out error:

```
activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
```

It seems that there is no db connection during the load time. What's the right way to load the mail server config? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to load it from the DB?  Usually you either load from a file or an environment variable.  Also take a look at `config.after_initialize` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

Comment: Yes, the mail config params need to be loaded from database table.

Comment: config.after_initialize works. Thanks  : config.after_initialize do
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = eval(Authentify::AuthentifyUtility.find_config_const('development_smtp_setting'))
  end

Comment: Great!  FWIW `eval` is a MAJOR security risk! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty  You're better off parsing the string, or storing it as JSON or YAML and using the built in parsers.  This post is a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object  This will be MUCH safer and probably faster too!  You can even have rails do the encode and decode for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database

Comment: We don't eval user input and only eval our own code stored in readonly table.