# Saving multiple checkbox outputs to single object attribute using HTML in a Rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, strong-parameters

I am trying to convert an HTML survey into a Rails app, but have encountered difficulties when attempting to carry over the functionality of checkboxes. Briefly, the problem is that checking the the checkboxes and then submitting the survey saves nothing in the database.

My model:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base

partial_updates = false
include ActiveModel::Serialization
serialize :checkbox_question, Hash

end
```

My controller:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @survey = Survey.new
 end

 def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 private
 def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:question_one, :question_two, . . ., {:checkbox_question => {}})
 end
end
```

Creating survey attributes for each of the checkbox would be possible, but it would drastically increase the size of my model and database. I don't want to take this approach if I can avoid it.

Here is the HTML for the new survey view:

```
. . .
<%= f.fields_for :checkbox_question, @survey.checkbox_question |p| %> 
  <%= p.check_box :option_one %><label>Option 1</label> 
  <%= p.check_box :option_two %><label>Option 2</label> 
  <%= p.check_box :option_three %><label>Option 3</label> 
<% end %>
. . .
<div class="submit step" id="complete"> 
<i class="icon-check"></i> 
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>  
</div>
```

When I create a new survey, use the checkboxes, and then submit it, the checkbox values are not saved in the relevant attributes—though all of the other fields save correctly. Moreover, if I insert “raise survey_params.insert” at the top of the Create action in my controller, then submit a new survey, request parameters includes the checkbox values as being checked. For example, if I check boxes 1 and 3 in the first checkbox section it returns:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0tmM1/CXRY9XYA/3tdzBZ6frTom8EGZvaYlq3EEE6vc=", "survey"=>{"question_one"=>"answer 1", "question_two"=>"answer 2", . . .  "checkbox_question"=>{"option_one"=>"1", "option_two"=>"0", "option_three"=>"1"} . . . .}
```

So, the Rails form that I am using appears to be working. It just seems unable to save.

I have attempted the fixes to similar-sounding problems described here (http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/4/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-partial-updates), here ([Using Rails serialize to save hash to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database)), and here (https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/issues/83), all with no luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Pro tip: if you want to get some help make this question 10 times shorter. Also use code to explain code, not words (i.e. models and associations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove "serialize :checkbox_question, Hash" from the model. Then, in the controller change "{:checkbox_question => {}}" to just ":checkbox_question".

Now, try passing that field separately as a string array.

```
<%= check_box_tag "checkbox_question_one[option_one]" %><label>Option 1</label>
<%= check_box_tag "checkbox_question_one[option_two]" %><label>Option 1</label> 
<%= check_box_tag "checkbox_question_one[option_three]" %><label>Option 1</label>
```

Then in your controller under create do something like:

```
@hash = params[:checkbox_question]

@string = ""
@hash.each do |key, value|
  if @hash[key] == "1"
    @string = @string + key + ","
  end
end

@survey.checkbox_question_one = @string
# "option_one,option_three"
```

And whenever you need the values, grab them with split...

```
foo = @survey.checkbox_question_one.split(',')
# ["option_one", "option_three"]
```

Comment: Just tried it. No luck. I'm getting two different errors. First a NoMethodError for an undefined method 'join' for {"option_one"=>"1", "option_three"=>"1"}. Second, a NoMethodError for an undefined method 'split'. I also tried removing the "serialize :checkbox_question" from my model and the corresponding notation in the survey_params in the controller. Again, same error.

Comment: OK, after some more tinkering, I think I've gotten it to work! Had to remove "serialize :checkbox_question" from my model, plus the notation in the survey_params. Then I iterated through the hash and added the key name to a string only if its value in the hash was "1". Then I saved the resulting string to @survey.checkbox_question. Then the "split" error went away in the view. Thank you!