# how do I save this data structure in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

how do I save this data structure in the database?

```
{
  amount => [{year => total_cost}],
  amount => [{year => total_cost}],
  amount => [{year => total_cost}]
}
```

Comment: look into activerecord serialize  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database

Answer (score 1):

Look into [PostgreSQL's hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html) feature. It is built for this very situation.