# How should I deal with JSON data and store then display again in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, database

I am using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.1.5.

Let's say I have a textarea can have users input some data in JSON format as below.

```
{ 
   "City" : "Japan", 
   "Population" : "20M"
}
```

What should I do to deal with this data in JSON format so I can re-use it to display again in JSON format in the future?

How do I store it in my database or any other way can do it?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: this can help you maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database

Comment: you can use `hstore` in `postgres` database

Comment: You could just store it as a string and then use `JSON.parse` to parse it back as `JSON` later. might want to validate that it is formatted appropriately if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can use the JSON columns.

See the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) on JSON with PostgreSQL.

Otherwise, if you are using other relational database (MySQL, Sqlite) use text/blob columns.