# Rails: designing a model with unknown attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, smartercsv

In my app I have a model called `Address`. The `address` field therein is the **only** required field, but the model can have any number of different other attributes.

Addresses will be created by importing rows from a `.csv` file. The CSV *has* to have an `address` column but may have many others, and they can be anything else and therefore impossible to predict.

How can I store this information accurately without having to add new DB columns each time? Can I make something like an `extra` DB column that stores information from columns not in the model? Can I run queries on that field (albeit bastardized)? Finally, when *exporting* this information back into CSV can I export that `extra` information back out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use Postgres as a database and have a table with 2 columns: `address` and `data` where data is of `jsonb` type. What that gives you is an ability to push arbitrary key/value data. You still can query it via SQL and have indexes on those fields.

Alternative would be to use a NoSQL database like Mongo or Couch.

Comment: Just discovered Store in Rails 4. Seems exactly what I was after?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data as `JSON` in any `text` type column.. and retrieve it like

```
<% @applicant_user_workflow_step.properties.each do |key, value| %>
      <tr>
        <td><strong><%= key %> </strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= value %></td>
      </tr>
 <% end %>
```

or

```
<%= fields_for :properties, OpenStruct.new(@applicant_user_workflow_step.properties) do |builder| %>
      <% @workflow_step.fields.order(:order_value).each do |field| %>
        <div class="row">
          <% if field.field_type.eql?('rating') %>
            <%= render "applicants/fields/application_custom_rating/rating", field: field, f: builder %>
          <% else %>
            <%= render "applicants/fields/#{field.field_type}", field: field, f: builder %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

[Openstruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) allows you to access `key` as `instance` methods for a `hash`

or simplly follow this
blog: http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms?view=asciicast
answer: [Using Rails serialize to save hash to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database)