# Extract elements from a string representing an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string

My message object has a link attribute `@message.link`, which is a string. Before saving message.link to db I `URI.extract` from message.body:

```
["http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs", "http://paulgraham.com/re.html"]
```

Once I save it to the db message.link will be saved as:

```
"[\"http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs\", \"http://paulgraham.com/re.html\"]"
```

When I fetch the data from db later on how can I get the array from the message.link string like this?

```
["http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs", "http://paulgraham.com/re.html"]
```

To display the links from all message objects, how should I extract the links? Let's say `message(1).link` has one link, `message(2)` has three links, and I'd like to display all the four links as separated elements of `@message_links` or whatever instance variable.

UPDATE

Method works but can't display the :created_at and do the pagination properly since @message_links2 will be an array of links.

```
@message_links = @conversation.messages.with_link.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
@message_links2 = @message_links.map(&:link).flatten
```

Comment: That is invalid. Do you mean `"[\"http`...?

Comment: Yeah, I meant like this: "[\"http://paulgraham.com/re.html\"]"

Comment: You fixed where you shouldn't have. Now, it's wrong in the other way.

Comment: sawa, I'm confused. If I do the URI extract from message.body I get: ["http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs", "http://paulgraham.com/re.html"], and then I save it to the db as message.link. Then I fetch the data from the db and I get back "[\"http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs\", \"http://paulgraham.com/re.html\"]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you want a serialized column. Then you won't need to do the conversion yourself.  see: [Using Rails serialize to save hash to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database)

Comment: you can display all the items from an array using flatten and map: `@messages.map(&:link).flatten => [link, link, link, link]`

Comment: court3nay, what I don't get is how you can mix the different objects. In this example the first link belongs to message(1) and the other three to message(2)?

Comment: Yes. Since it's not obvious what you want to do with the links, I'm giving you some general ruby ideas  :) You might want to make a separate class/table for links with has_many association

Comment: Basically, when a user creates a chat message the link gets saved, so the users can find all the links from a conversation. I'm not sure if I need a new class. I will just display the links as a list (kinda index page), and if user click on one of them then gets to the given page. So besides recognizing links in chat messages and displaying them I do nothing with the links. What do you think? Do I need a separate class?

Comment: court3nay, plz take a look at the updated question. I would like to display 12 links with created_at attribute, but since @message_links2 is an array I can't call the pagination on it and it doesn't contain the created_at date. If I call the pagination on the message.with_links objects like in the current code then the number of links will vary since it's unknown how many links an object has.

Comment: I think you should keep links in a separate table and paginate on that. if you did that, you'd be finished already :) you can easily extract 'em out with a callback.