# How allows users adding they own fields on site to the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How creating the possibility for user editing the fields of the model, like creating custom forms, and fields in it?

Thanks for ideas and answers)

Comment: As written, this question is at best, ambiguous and at worse unintelligible. Perhaps you know someone who can help you phrase the question in a manner that would attract answers for you.

Comment: Yura, Vse lehko. Tebe nado database table sohranyat v {Hash: data}. Smotra kakuyu database polzuessa. Tochno znayu 4to PostgreSQL ili MongoDB podderjivaet, s MySQL ne proboval eshe, no doljen podderjivat toje.

Comment: I noticed your username contains Cyrillic. If you are more proficient at Russian than English, then consider using the Russian language Stack Overflow. If you speak a different language like Ukrainian or Mongolian, we don't have any Stack Overflow sites yet.

Comment: I can not understand, why: hi, hello and etc., deleted when I post the question

Comment: About why "hi" and the like is removed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1):

You want the model to contain custom fields inputted by the user. How would you call on the fields if the names/keys of the field are custom input? The fields would not make sense to save as columns in the database. You don't want your users actually editing the model or your database schema; you just want to process their input in a different way.

To store the sets of custom field/value pairs for each user, you would need to serialize and save a hash of custom fields in your User table. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database) for an example.